Sitecore Analytics: Subsite Filter disabled for users with restricted access to a single domain
I am experiencing an issue with the "Subsite" filter in Sitecore Analytics (version 10.3.2) when a user has restricted access to a single domain.
The Subsite filter lists all domains (or subsites) for which analytics data has been collected, and it works fine for the Admin and other users that have access to multiple domains. However, when a user has access to only one domain/country (e.g., UK) the dropdown filter is disabled and the domain is not selected.
The following screenshot is from the "Pages" section:

When I remove the "disabled" HTML attribute I can see that the domain is listed in the dropdown options. Also, I've noticed that the "Subsite" parameter is not present by default in the URL along with the other filter options, and if I add it manually (by appending &subsite=<domain_name>) the dropdown remains disabled, but the domain is selected properly and the Analytics data is filtered according to the selection. In addition to that, the option can be set using the scExperienceAnalytics_Subsite cookie, however, this could be just another temporary workaround.
On the other hand, when a user has access to multiple domains, sometimes no domain is selected, but the dropdown is not disabled, at least, and the user is able to make the selection.
I suspect the issue may origin from the JavaScript logic responsible for initializing the component:
\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ExperienceAnalytics\Common\Layouts\Renderings\SubsiteFilter.js, but before implementing any custom fixes, I wanted to ensure that this is a known issue and if there is an official solution, patch, or configuration that ensures the Subsite filter is enabled and pre-selects the appropriate domain.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into this behavior, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance!
